# Multiple Instances of the Same Microservice BUT with Different Secrets

Tags: c#, kubernetes, microservices

I would like to run 3 instances of the same exact microservice but would also like that each microservice will read from a different secret with unique parameters and database connection string.

1. Is this something that can be configured in Kubernetes?
2. In case we decide not to use Kubernetes, what is the best way to associate a microservice instance with its secret (appsettings?).

Comment: All of the replicas of a Deployment are identical; in a StatefulSet, they'll have different storage and predictable names but otherwise will also be identical.  The linked question has a couple of workarounds (more useful for the StatefulSet case) or you could create a separate Deployment for each separate backing database.

Comment: Yes you can. You need to create two deployment sets for each of the pod/microservice and pass the unique keys that you want to pass from the secret to each of the pods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you say: same exact microservice, do you mean "same image" or "same deployment"? Are these part of the same replicaset or they are "independent"? Is this a multi-tenant where each "instance" is processing requests for a tenant?

If they are different deployments, they that can easily be done because in k8s they are different and each can have it's own config/secrets.

If they are the same deployment/replicaset; then I'd question why you need this?